# Pycharm: multiple tabs all with same name; how to highlight active file in project explorer?

Tags: django, pycharm

With a number of different apps that all have their own version of "admin.py" and "views.py," etc., I have a hard time telling which one I have open when looking at the tabs (the tabs don't have the full path).

Is there a way to highlight which file I'm editing in the active tab?  Normally with programs that use this format -- for instance Gmail -- the active section or file is highlighted on the left, but not so in PyCharm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `View` | `Select In` | `Project View` or enable **Autoscroll from Source** option in the Project View.

In PyCharm **2.0** there will be **Show directory in editor tabs for non-unique filenames** option in `Settings` | `Editor` | `Editor Tabs`.

Comment: Initially the "Project View" highlights the file with focus in the editor, but then goes back to the slight outline with small dots.  Is there a way to keep that highlight always?  And thank you.

Comment: no, it's the way selection/focus works in the JTree component.

Answer (score 0):

The project pane should have a row of buttons on the top. Mouse over them for tooltips, and look for the one that says "Autoscroll from source". Make sure to make the sidebar wide enough to see all the buttons.

Comment: Jolly good, sir.  I see a slight outline of small dots, which is rather hard to see.  Is there a way to have it pop out with a shadow color or something?  Thank you very much, though.